# Install JUST the `dist/` folder of the repo?

Tags: jspm

When I `jspm install` certain packages, what looks like the entire source of the dependency is downloaded.  I'm all about reviewing the full source of something I incorporate, but the packages folder of a consuming app doesn't seem like the right place for it.  Is there a way to specify a *source* subfolder (ie `dist/`) for pulling rather than the repo's root folder?  If this is documented, I'm having trouble teasing such search results apart from other posts about overriding the *destination* folder.